# Database values updated but not visible in the client side angular web application

Tags: angularjs, http

I have working angularjs and HTML web application. The problem that I am facing is that it doesn't updates the data changed in the server. But if I run it with debugger it works fine and updates the data as expected.

For example:  script file

```
 $http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/database')
.then(function(objectList){
    $scope.objectList = objectList.data;
});
```

html file

```
<tr ng-repeat="object in objectList">
```

now when I revisit the page after adding new object to the objectList using `location.path()` and `routeProvider` the I can't see the newly added item in the list while if I perform the same activity with the debugger of browser open then I can see the new object in the `List`. However the data is added to the database at server side successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOund the Solution to above question.

```
//initialize get if not there
    if (!$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = {};    
    }    

    // Answer edited to include suggestions from comments
    // because previous version of code introduced browser-related errors

    //disable IE ajax request caching
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['If-Modified-Since'] = 'Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT';
    // extra
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Pragma'] = 'no-cache';
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice would be to have a someService.js file for all the API requests and you can use that service in your controller. Moreover, you can set the scope variable as an empty array globally and then after resolving the promise you can push the success.data into the scope variable and it should work like a charm.

This should be in your controller:

```
$scope.objectList = [];
var databasePromise = someservice.getDatabase();
databasePromise.then(function(success) {
   $scope.objectList = success.data;
}, function(failure) {
   console.log(failure);
});
```

Please share a plunker, if you are having a hard time fixing it.

Comment: Used the Service file you suggested. But the issue is when I run the application in browser with browser debugger open, everything is working as expected and the values of the templates gets updated but not when the debugger of the browser is closed as if it is getting the previous instance of pages or http request and not the fresh instance

Comment: Hmm. that sounds weird. Do you mind sharing the code in private repository, where I can take a deep look into it?